# Python: Applying threshold to a numpy array

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Given this dict of `numpy.ndarray`:

```
d={0: np.array([[  9.81650352,  10.03896523,  10.26972675],  [11.76386738,
          11.76718712,  11.63769531]]),
   1: np.array([[  13.33630352,  29.17866523,  17.1005102675],  [41.98976738,
          6.44368712,  2.11764771]])}
```

And the following threshold:

```
t=10
```

I want to have a new dict with `1` if each float value in d is `>=t`, and `0` if it is `<t`. My attempt

```
newd={k:[[1]] or [[0]] for k,[[v]] in d if [[v]]>=t}
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-152-68383ed9ad79>", line 1, in <module>
    newd={k:[[1]] or [[0]] for k,[[v]] in d if [[v]]>=17}

  File "<ipython-input-152-68383ed9ad79>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
    newd={k:[[1]] or [[0]] for k,[[v]] in d if [[v]]>=17}

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How should I "rephrase" my snippet?

The intended outcome would be, in this example:

```
newd={0: np.array([[ 0,  1,  1],  [1, 1,  1]]),
      1: np.array([[ 1,  1,  1],  [1, 0,  0]])}
```

Comment: Looks tricky, but for starters I suggest using `d.items`. Right now you're only iterating over d's keys.

Comment: Where is `array()` coming from?

Comment: Of course `array()` is an `np.ndarray`. My bad...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as :

```
>>> new_d = {k:np.where(v >= 10, 1, 0) for k, v in d.iteritems()}
>>> {0: array([[0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]]), 1: array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]])}
```

The `np.where` method takes the condition as first param and two values `x` and `y`. If both x and y are specified, the output array contains elements of x where condition is True, and elements from y elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{0: array([[  9.81650352,  10.03896523,  10.26972675],
       [ 11.76386738,  11.76718712,  11.63769531]]),
 1: array([[ 13.33630352,  29.17866523,  17.10051027],
       [ 41.98976738,   6.44368712,   2.11764771]])}
```

Create a boolean arrays

```
>>> d2 = {k:v > t for k,v in d.items()}
>>> pprint(d2)
{0: array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool),
 1: array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)}
```

Then multiply by one

```
>>> d3 = {k: v * 1 for k, v in d2.items()}
>>> pprint(d3)
{0: array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
 1: array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])}
>>>
```

In a single *step*:

```
>>> d4 = {k : 1 * (v > t) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> pprint(d4)
{0: array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]]),
 1: array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0]])}
>>>
```

---

I started with this approach because I just don't distinguish between True/False and 1/0 - they are equivalent to me.  But maybe using numpy.where is the better solution.

Comment: Upvoted. Closer to the idea I originally had in mind. But...convinced by `np.where` :)